# Problem with Child Of Location

Tags: animation

I'm learning Blender and am following a spiderman tutorial ( https://youtu.be/UO0OM0plOX0?t=773 ) .. but I've been battling a serious problem for several days now and can't find the solution. Maybe someone can help ? I use Blender 2.92 and when I insert the Keyframe when letting go of the Web at around 13:00 it actually puts the (ChildOf-)Empty to the starting position and not to the current position? So My "web" just snaps around weirdly and does not at all behave as it should.. (when I observe the Empty's location coordinates the don't move at all either, but the empty moves, beeing linked to the hand)..

https://youtu.be/UO0OM0plOX0?t=773

Here 3 pics of the problem :

Here pic 1, start of animation "Empty" is selected Location is shown : [image]

Then 1st Keyframe : [image] (Location unchanged)

Then the frame right afterwards where the Empty snaps back to original location :

[image]

Comment: Can you put screenshots instead of requiring following the YouTube link?

Comment: Yes of course, sorry.

Here pic 1, start of animation "Empty" is selected Location is shown : https://pasteall.org/media/b/0/b01f3c51bc306157bc0015d1f80a0b02.png

Then 1st Keyframe : https://pasteall.org/media/3/e/3efe87d74a985b3c992f031dd414ab31.png 5Location unchanged)

Then the frame right afterwards where the Empty snaps back to original location :

https://pasteall.org/media/2/3/23f907c9052a0340ea2f6c72566d717e.png

Comment: Can you edit them into the question?

Comment: Did it right away, sorry, new to StackExchange..

Comment: Ok, that’s good formatting. Hmm, the child of constraint would not be adequate to leave the empty in the correct position... maybe it’s backwards, or you forgot to animate something?

Comment: Have a look at 'Method 2' at the link below.  I think @Moonboots came up with this and it sounds like it could solve your problem.  I'll have to spend time and find the original post for future reference when I have time.  To repeat myself, "Method 2". The link -
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/154199/how-to-sequence-paths/154777#154777

Comment: Cont from above...  Follow 'Method 2's instructions down to the line - "You can now move the timeline. The model is again free and unconstrained".  If you run into trouble there is another option - bake the model's action.  That will free it of all constraints when you tick all the Baking panel's boxes.  A 3rd option is to split the action between two Blend files.  More details available if you need them.